# How to fix the issue the response says TypeError: toClient is not a function

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to send the response to the client after query execution, so I wrote a callback `toClient()` and then `queryEx(toClient)` but it returns a typeerror.

```
router.get('/', function (req,res) {
    let packet = sp.mapper(req);
    let output = null;

    function toClient() {
        res.send(output);
    }

    function queryEx(toClient) {
        output = QueryExe.execute(packet);

        toClient();
    }

    queryEx();
})
```

Error:

> toClient is not a function
>   TypeError: toClient is not a function

Comment: You don't need to pass it to `qureyEx`. It's already available inside it, since it's declared outside. Besides, you're calling `qureyEx()` without passing it any argument. It's exactly like you call `qureyEx(undefined)`. Therefore `toClient` becomes undefined inside `qureyEx`.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `toClient` on function `queryEx` is swallowing the declaration of the function `toClient()`. Try to rename either the function or the parameter.

```
let packet = sp.mapper(req);
let output = null;

function toClient() {
    res.send(output);
}

function queryEx(toClientParam /*I don't know the use of this param*/) {
    output = QueryExe.execute(packet);

    toClient();
}

queryEx();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in your callback here.

You have to specify `toClient` when you call `queryEx();`

This should result in something like this :

```
queryEx(toClient);
```

Why I'm doing this is because this is how callbacks work. Just renaming the functions to something else is a sign of bad practice ;)